# what's the difference between php-curl and browser call php script to send a http request?

Tags: firebase, nginx, post, firebase-cloud-messaging, php-curl

I am trying to push notification from server to all android devices with the same topic calling Google firebase cloud messaging api(HTTP v1),however,http response says 411 error code which stands for POST requests require a Content-length header, but I do add content-length in http post request header.then I put the script under www directory of a host, and call this script using browser,the resquest is successful, so how come two way of sending http requests receiving different results? what does nginx do in the process so make the request successful?
ps:I f12 open the console and paste the header into php curl header, still does not work, what is missing, so confusing..

```
$topic = 'xxxxx';
    $projectId = 'xxxx';
    $title = 'hahaha';
    $content = 'lol';

    $payload = array(
        'message' => array(
            'topic' => $topic,
            'notification' => array(
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $content,
            )
        )
    );

    $json = json_encode($payload);
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:Bearer '.$this->getFcmApiAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type: application/json; UTF-8',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
        'Cookie: hrg_session=30d4sk8ue8jbe795m3aavrgv97ds4n9g',
        'Host: test.hrgame.com.hk',
        'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36',
    );

    print_r($headers);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$projectId}/messages:send");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($result);exit;
```

Error 411 (Length Required)!!1

POST requests require a `Content-length` header.  That’s all we know.

[google api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x3OL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I changed php to python to send post request, and it send the request successfully. still don't know what's the problem with the php curl lib